# htaccess RewriteRule - pattern not matching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use categories in a clean way in my urls like this:

website.com/category

In the url the categories are written like this: Some random examples:

Animals
Consumer-Electronics
Books-&-Comics
External-Hard-Discs
Form,-Beauty-&-Health
Black-&-White-TV
The-Adventures-Of-Tintin
Fryers,-Waffle-makers-&-Cooking
etc...

As you can see, there is a random combination of words (with starting upper case), characters "-", ",", and "&". There are more combinations than the examples.

With rewrite I'm trying to get the categories in a variable like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-&]+)$ /categories.php?mcn=$1 [L,NC]
```

This is not working. If I read out the variable I wanted with "Books-&-Comics" in categories.php, I only get "Books-" while it should be "Books-&-Comics".

When I add a "," in the character class like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w,-&]+)$ /categories.php?mcn=$1 [L,NC]
```

I get an internal server error.

How should my RewriteRule look like to match the category examples and get them correctly in the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, the issue is that your parameters are being decoded and thus the `&` is starting a new URL parameter. You can fix this by adding a `B` flag to your rule.

Your second issue is that the pattern `^([\w,-&]+)$` is invalid. It is trying to match any word character, or any character between `,` and `&`. (Ascii 44 & 38) because this is out of order, the regex fails. As you want to match the `-` character rather than using it as a range indicator, it should be escaped.

With these changes made your rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w,\-&]+)$ /categories.php?mcn=$1 [L,NC,B]
```

A regex helper like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) can be a huge help in creating your rules.

Comment: Ik looks like the B Flag is also an important one. It escapes Backreferences right?

Comment: @Thoaren, yes. That's correct - the B flag is what lets you use special characters in your URL by escaping back references.